# Run All LLVM Passes

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I've got a LLVM Module and I was wondering if there was an easy way to run all LLVM optimizations passes using the C++ API for -O3 (without having to register each pass individually).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the `PassManagerBuilder` class for it. You set the optimization level, and then ask it to populate a pass manager for you.

An easy way to see how it's done is to look at the source of `opt.cpp` in the LLVM repository - [right here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/tools/opt/opt.cpp#L206).